# MySQLdb install problem

Tags: python, installation, mysql

I need to install MySQLdb.

I write:

```
$ tar xfz MySQL-python-1.2.1.tar.gz
$ cd MySQL-python-1.2.1    
$ python setup.py build    #it is ok
$ su root setup.py install    #return list of errors
```

error list:

- setup.py: line 3: import: command not
  found
- setup.py: line 4: import: command not
  found-
- setup.py: line 5: from: command not
  found-
- setup.py: line 7: syntax error
  nearunexpected token '('-
- setup.py: line 7: 'if not
  hasattr(sys, "hexversion") or
  sys.hexversion < 0x02030000:'

What's wrong?

Comment: I am not sure `root` is needed there, just try `su python setup.py install`

Comment: @S.Mark, on `su python setup.py install` - returned error `su: user python does not exist`.

Comment: ah, sorry, I was confused with `sudo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot an important word in your example: "python"

```
$ su root python setup.py install
```